# sshd_config file is being overwritten on reboot

Tags: password, authentication, openssh, sshd

I need an AWS server to accept password authentication and whenever I remove the hash and set 
PasswordAuthentication yes

After reboot or create image and launch a new instance, the # is added back to the line in the sshd_config file.  and then I get

Permission denied (publickey).

Does anyone know how to stop this file from being changed?